# Set SQL propery slow on Server 2012

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado

I have a problem with Server 2012 R2 Foundation and an application I wrote (Delphi 7 Pro).

There is a service that receives data over TCP, checks it against a MS SQL server database and returns data over TCP.

This service is currently running on multiple other servers all Server 2008.

Part of a Procedure that reads data form the DB

```
qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
try
  qry.ConnectionString := msConnectionString;

  LogEntry('Set SQL');
  qry.SQL.Text := 'Select * ' +
                  'from Users ' +
                  'where UserID = ' + QuotedStr(sUserID) +
                  ' and Password = ' + QuotedStr(sPassword);
  LogEntry('Open Qry');
  qry.Open;
  LogEntry('Open Qry - Done');      

  if qry.RecordCount = 0 then begin
    sUserName := '';
    iStatus   := 0;
  end else begin
    LogEntry('Set User Variables');      
    sUserName := qry.FieldByName('UserName').AsString;
    iStatus   := qry.FieldByName('Status').AsInteger;
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(qry);
end;
```

*LogEntry is a customer procedure that writes to a log file with timestamps.

The weird part is that in the above code the "qry.SQL.Text" is the part that takes long, it takes 2 seconds. Log Extract below :

```
[15:48:45]   Create Qry
[15:48:45]   Set Sql
[15:48:47]   Open Qry
[15:48:47]   Open Qry Done
```

What could the cause be for the simple property assignment to take this long.

If i move the code to a Simple project1 application the result is instant.

Comment: looks weird indeed, can you show us the code for LogEntry ?